# How to evaluate the integral $I = \int_o^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1}}\,dx$$.

I tried to solve by substituting $t = 2\pi\sqrt x \implies t^2 = 4{\pi}^2x \implies tdt = 2\pi^2dx$

$$I = \frac1{8\pi^4}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}dt.$$

But now I'm unable to solve from here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$I =  \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{2\pi\sqrt x}-1}}dx$$

Let
$$x = \frac{t^2}{4\pi^2} \implies dx = \frac{tdt}{2\pi^2}$$

Thus,
$$I =\frac1{8\pi^4} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}dt$$

Let's consider a more general integral.

$$f(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-st}}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}dt$$
$$\frac {df(s)}{ds^3}=f_3(s) = -\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^3e^{-st}}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}dt$$
$$\color{blue}{I = -\frac 1{8\pi^4}\left(\frac {df(s)}{ds^3}\right)_{s=0}}\text{...................#1}$$

Now,

$$u =e^{-t} \implies \ln u = -t \implies -\frac{du}{u} = dt$$

```
              +---------+--------+
       t -->> |    0    |   ∞    |
              +---------+--------+
       u -->> |    1    |   0    |
              +---------+--------+
```

$$\begin{align*}
f(s) 
& = \int_0^1 \frac{u^{s-1}}{\sqrt{\frac 1{u}-1}}du\\
& = \int_0^1 u^{s-\frac 1{2}}(1-u)^{-\frac1{2}}du\\
& = \beta \left(s+\frac 1{2}, \frac 1{2} \right)\\
& = \frac{\Gamma(s+\frac 1{2})\Gamma(\frac 1{2})}{\Gamma(s+1)}\\
& \implies \color{red}{f_1(s)} = \color{blue}{f(s)}\color{green}{\left(\psi_0\left(s+\frac 1{2}\right) - \psi_0(s+1)\right)} = \color{blue}{f}\color{green}{\times g}\\
\end{align*}$$

- **What is [$\psi$-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html)**
- **[Derivative of $\beta$-function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)**

$$\begin{align*}f_1 =
& f\times g\\
& \implies f_2 = f_1g + fg_1 = (fg)g+fg_1 = fg^2+fg_1\\
& \implies f_3 = f_1g^2+2fgg_1+f_1g_1+fg_2\\ 
& \implies f_3(s) = fg^3 + 3fgg_1 + fg_2 = \color{blue}{f(s)\left[g^3(s)+3g(s)g_1(s) + g_2(s)\right] = f_3(s)}\text{.................#2}\\
\end{align*}$$

let's find zeros of function
$$\color{green}{f(s=0)} = \beta\left(\frac 1{2}, \frac 1{2}\right) = \frac {\sqrt\pi\sqrt\pi}{1} = \color{green}{\pi}$$

- **$g(0)$**

$$\begin{align*} 
\color{green}{g(s)}  
& = \left(\psi_0(s+ \frac 1{2}) - \psi_0(s+1)\right) \\
&\implies g(s=0) = \left(\color{red}{\psi_0(\frac 1{2})} - \psi(1)\right) \\
&= (\color{red}{(-\gamma-2\ln2)}+\gamma) = \color{green}{-2\ln(2)}\\
\end{align*}$$

- **$g_1(0)$**
  $$\begin{align*} \color{green}{g_1(s)} 
  &= \left(\psi_1(s+ \frac 1{2}) - \psi_1(s+1)\right)\\
  &\implies g_1(0) = \left(\color{red}{\psi_1(\frac 1{2})} - \psi_1(1)\right)\\
  & = \left(\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right) = \color{green}{\frac{\pi^2}{3}}\\
  \end{align*}$$
- **$g_2(0)$**

$$\begin{align*}
\color{green}{g_2(s)} = 
&\left(\psi_2(s+ \frac 1{2}) - \psi_2(s+1)\right)\\
&\implies g_2(0) = \left(\color{red}{\psi_2( \frac 1{2})} - \psi_2(1)\right)\\
& = \color{red}{-14\zeta(3)} + 2\zeta(3) = \color{green}{-12\zeta(3)}
\end{align*}$$

From above
$$\begin{align*}I =
& -\frac 1{8\pi^4} f_3(0) = -\frac 1{8\pi^4}\left(\pi\left((-2\ln 2)^3 + 3(-2\ln 2)\times \frac{\pi^2}{3} 
 - 12\zeta(3)\right)\right)\\
& =  \frac {\ln^3(2)}{\pi^3} + \frac{\ln(2)}{4\pi} + \frac {3\zeta(3)}{2\pi^3}   \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You are so humble!

Comment: @ParvathiAyyangar Thanks✌️!

Comment: Nice trick! (+1)

Comment: Nice solution and $\to +1$. By the way, there is a  quite fast solution for the antiderivative using hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks! Now you hit my curiosity Would you like add your solution for me, please?

Comment: @DarshanPatil. Long and tedious to type. Cheers :-)

Comment: Very nice and so fascinating !

Answer (score 7):

*Too long for a comment.*

If we consider the problem of
$$I_n=\int \frac{t^n}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}dt$$ for $n>1$ they all write as
$$I_n=-2 t^n \sin ^{-1}\left(e^{-t/2}\right)-4ne^{-t/2} J_n$$ where $J_n$ are expressed in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions.

For example
$$J_2=t \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}
\right)+2 \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{
   2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}\right)$$
$$J_3=t^2 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}
\right)+4 t \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{
   2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}\right)+$$ $$8 \,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{
   2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}\right)$$
$$J_4=t^3 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}
\right)+6 t^2 \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{
   2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}\right)+$$ $$24 t \,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{
   2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}\right)+48 \,
   _6F_5\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{
   2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};e^{-t}\right)$$

where we can notice simple patterns.

Now, for the definite integrals
$$K_n=\frac 1 \pi\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{\sqrt{e^t-1}}dt$$ the term $2 t^n \sin ^{-1}\left(e^{-t/2}\right)$ disappears and  we  have for the first ones
$$K_2=\frac{\pi ^2}{3}+4  \log ^2(2)$$
$$K_3=2 \pi ^2 \log (2)+8 \log ^3(2)+12 \zeta (3)$$
$$K_4=8 \pi ^2 \log ^2(2) +16 \log ^4(2)+96 \zeta (3) \log (2)+114 \zeta(4) $$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @DarshanPatil. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\;x=\dfrac{y^2}{\pi^2},\;$ then
$$I=\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{x\,\text dx}{\sqrt{e^{2\pi\sqrt x}-1}}
=\dfrac2{\pi^4}\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{y^3\,\text dy}{\sqrt{e^{2y}-1}}
=\dfrac2{\pi^4}\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{y^3 e^{-y}\,\text dy}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2y}}}
=-\dfrac2{\pi^4}\int\limits_0^\infty y^3\,\text d\arcsin e^{-y}$$
$$\overset{\text{IBP}}{=\!=}\;\dfrac6{\pi^4}\int\limits_0^\infty y^2 \arcsin e^{-y}\,\text dy
=\dfrac6{\pi^4}\int\limits_0^1 \ln^2 z\, \dfrac{\arcsin z}z\,\text dz
=\dfrac{1}{8\pi^3}\big(12\zeta(3)+\ln^3 4\ +\pi^2\ln4\big).$$
[image: Integration]