# In an attempt to find $I = \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, laplace-transform, riemann-zeta, polygamma

I was trying to solve $I = \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$

- My approach

I took the more general form of integral $f(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{e^t-1}dt$ the same way as [How to evaluate the integral $I = \int_o^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^{2\pi\sqrt{x}}-1}}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292020/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-i-int-o-infty-fracx-sqrte2-pi-sqrtx/4292035#4292035)

So, my answer $$I = -\left[\frac{\partial f(s)}{\partial s}\right]_{s =0}$$ but that simply doesn't work.

However, [$\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$ without using series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288074/int-0-infty-fractet-1dt-without-using-series/4288093#4288093) doesn't answer my question as I'm interested in finding why finding derivative at $s = 0$ doesn't work

Also, *I'm interested in finding a number of different ways I can solve this problem*

Comment: @Darshan Patil Can you help me understand why differentiating doesn't work just the way you solved https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292020/how-to-evaluate-the-integral-i-int-o-infty-fracx-sqrte2-pi-sqrtx/4292035#4292035

Comment: @Parvathi Ayyangar, the differentiation do works.

Comment: The Laplace Transform $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{e^t-1}\,dt$ fails to exist and hence discussion of its derivative is meaningless.

Comment: Laplace transform will work, if you regularize the integrand at $t=0$. Take, for instance, $I(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-st}}{e^t-1}dt$. This integral converges, and $\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial s^n}I(s)\Big|_{s=0}$. Making change $x=e^{-t}$
$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-t^s}{1-t}dt=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{1}{k+s}-\frac{1}{k}\Big)=\gamma+\psi(1+s)$$
where $\psi(x)$ - digamma function. For $n>0$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial s^n}\psi(s+1)\Big|_{s=0}=(-1)^{n+1}\psi^{(n)}(1)=n!\zeta(n+1)$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well! This integral is really interesting and has a lot to do with [Bernoulli's Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html), [Riemann Zeta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), [Polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html), in the last what you were trying is nothing less than [Laplace Transformation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html)

$$I = \int_0^{\infty}\frac {t}{e^t-1}dt$$

First I'll try to answer why $$I =-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^{\infty}\frac {e^{-st}}{e^t-1}dt$$ is failing to conclude answer and after that, I'll try to add few other ways you can conclude to the answer.

- **Why $I =-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^{\infty}\frac {e^{-st}}{e^t-1}dt$ fails**

**Answer** On the very first look you can conclude that the definite integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac {e^{-st}}{e^t-1}dt$ doesn't exist(Undefined)

**Hint** Lower limit of definite integral is $0$ and when $t =0 $ numerator = $1$ but denominator $=0$ However, for $\int_0^{\infty}\frac {t}{e^t-1}dt$ it's totally different
Even if you try to find by taking laplace transformation you'll eventually end up for $\Gamma(0)$

- **How to solve using Transformation only?**
  [This may answer your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288074/int-0-infty-fractet-1dt-without-using-series/4288093#4288093) but as you asked for a few other ways to solve this integral I'm adding a few transformation based answers.
- **$1$] Using Laplace Transform Identity**
  I'm unable to provide a link from where I found this but if I could remember you can find it in "Handbook of Mathematics for Engineer's & Scientists" by Andrei & Alexander

If
$$\begin{align*}
F(s) = \mathcal{L}f(t) 
&= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt\\
& \implies \sum_{s=1}^{\infty}F(s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac {f(t)}{e^t-1}dt\\
& \text{We can put } f(t) = t \implies \mathcal{L}(t) = \frac 1{s^2}\\
& \text{Thus,}\\
& \color{green}{I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt = \sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{s^2}=\zeta(2) = \frac {\pi^2}{6}}\\
\end{align*}$$

- [**$2]$ Using diagamma function**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)

$$\begin{align*}
I 
&= \int_0^{\infty}\frac t{e^t-1}dt\\
& \text{We substitute, } e^{-t} = x \implies t = -\ln x \implies dt = -\frac{dx}{x} \\ 
& \color{blue}{I = -\int_0^1 \frac {\ln x}{1-x}dx}\\
\end{align*}$$

Now,
$$\color{red}{\psi_0 (z) = -\gamma + \int_0^{1} \frac {1-x^{z-1}}{1-x}dx}$$
We'll differentiate and that is [trigamma function $\psi_1(z)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html)

$$\implies \frac {\partial\psi_0}{\partial z}= \psi_1 (z) = -\int_0^1 \frac {x^{z-1}\ln x}{1-x}dx$$
$$\color{green}{I = \left[\psi_1(z)\right]_{z=1} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}}$$

- **$3]$ Using the integral form of even values of zeta function**

$$\left|\zeta(2n) = \frac 1{(2n-1)!}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{e^x-1}dx\right|_{n =1}$$

- **$4]$ More general form of the above integral in terms of Bernoulli's Number**

$$\left|\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n-1}}{e^{px}-1}dx = (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac {2\pi}{p}\right)^{2n} \frac{B_{2n}}{4n}\right|_{n, p = 1, 1}$$
[$B_2 = \frac 1{6}$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html)

- **My last attempt: The cosine Transformation**

$$f_c(u) = \int_0^{\infty}f(x)\cos(ux)dx$$

for $$\text{if  }f(x) = \frac x{e^{ax}-1} \implies f_c(u) = \frac 1{2u^2} - \frac {\pi^2}{2a^2\sinh^2(\pi a^{-1}u)} $$
I tried to take the limit as $u \to 0$ but didn't work maybe because cosine transformation is defined for $u \in (0, \infty)$ but at $u = 0.0001$ it's $f_c(u = 0.0001) = 1.644934043288231 ≈ \pi^2/6$

Comment: Woww! You made that this is more than enough!

Comment: Thanks! This is what exactly I was looking you explained why differentiating was failing.

Comment: You mentioned polygamma function but I didn't find polygamma function in your answer? I would like to know

Comment: @ParvathiAyyangar Yes, I didn't mention but you can read on it 
**Hint** [$\psi_1(1)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) $= \zeta(2) = \frac {\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: + for the first laplace transform Identity!

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t-1} dt &= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{te^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-nt}  dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}te^{-nt}  \,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left.\left(-\frac{e^{-nt}(nt+1)}{n^2}\right)\right|_0^\infty \\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\\\\&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}$$

The last sum is well known as the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and I'll let you fill in the details of interchanging summation and integration.

Comment: the op asked how to solve the integral using the generalized integral he mentioned and taking its derivative at $0$.

Comment: True, their last sentence also said they were interested in finding a number of different ways to solve the problem

Comment: The link he mentions already contains those answers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{t^{2-1}}{e^t-1}\,\text dt = \Gamma(2)\zeta(2)
=\dfrac{\pi^2}6$$
([Riemann zeta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html))